# How can I change a SASS property with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

```
$baseFontSize: 16;
$green: #1abc9c;
$yellow: #f1c40f;
$red: #c0392b;
$blue: #3498db;
$grey: #f2f2f2;

@function rem($val) {
  @return #{$val / $baseFontSize}rem;
}
```

I want to dynamically change property `baseFontSize`.

Can I do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.......
```

Comment: you cannot, the is SASS/LESS that comes before rendring the page, you only have access to the generated CSS.

Comment: When do you want to change the value of `baseFont`? I guess when when you click on some custom zoom button. Just change the value of `font-size` of `<HTML/>` and `<BODY/>`.

Answer (score 1):

No, There is no a way to add CSS from SASS or LESS, Use JavaScript, Which is the following example can be helpful to you.

```
//remove style sheet
var sheetToBeRemoved = document.getElementById(styleID);
if (sheetToBeRemoved) {
 var sheetParent = sheetToBeRemoved.parentNode;
 sheetParent.removeChild(sheetToBeRemoved);
}

//add style sheet
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.type = 'text/css';
sheet.id = styleID;
sheet.innerHTML = css;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sheet)
//document.body.appendChild(sheet);

//apply class to body
element.addClass(baseFontSizeClass);
```

[Demo:](https://e2ecode.blogspot.com/2015/01/dynamic-style-manipulating-css-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, `$baseFontSize` is calculated when the app is built, that means it finish and become static value (not variable) before you run the script. So in the final `css`, there'll be nothing call `$baseFontSize` anymore.

You can override the value of a specific class, but can't override a sass variable, as it is not in the js scope

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to change the `$baseFontSize` variable dynamically with JavaScript as the sass will have been compiled to css by the time you are trying to use your javascript on it.

If you are just wanting to increase the base document size (so all other rem size values increase with it), then you can increase the font size on the [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)

The below example shows a document with a base font size of 16px increasing to 30px and how it would affect anything sized with rem

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.test {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script>
function changeRootSize() {
    document.documentElement.style.fontSize = '30px';
}
</script>
<div class="test" onclick="changeRootSize()">
  click me
</div>
```